# CString.Replace replace more than one character

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to use the CString.replace method and seem to not be replacing the rest of the string.

```
tmpStr.Replace(_T('in.'), _T(' '));
```

is the specific line. I want to remove all instances of the string "in." in the CString tmpStr. But it seems it only to replace the 'i' in "in." with a space. And the rest it leave alone.

Is there a way to replace a string with a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not calling the overload that you intend to call. [`CString::Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ztyt5e9c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload that takes two characters, that's the one your function call invokes. Change `'in.'` to `"in."` (note the double quotes instead of single quotes). Similarly, change `' '` to `" "`.

`'in.'` is a multicharacter literal, and how this is interpreted is implementation defined. It seems VC just considers it to be the same as `i`.